# Easy Deployer Bundle fails on symlinking parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, symfony-3.3

I am trying to use easy-deploy-bundle to deploy a symfony project cannot deploy any symfony project, even to my local machine.  The symlinking for the parameters.yml file from the shared directory always fails with the error below.

I have cloned the symfony-demo project, this is a symfony 3.3.10, the parameters.yml file is empty but present in the shared/app/config dir.

Error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  The command "(export SYMFONY_ENV=prod; cd /home/patrick/code/testedb-deploy/releases/20171015162057 && ln -nfs /home/patrick/code/testedb-deploy/shared/app/config/parameters.yml /home/patrick/code/testedb-deploy/releases/20171015162057/app/config/parameters.yml)" f  
  ailed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

  Exit Code: 1(General error)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

  Working directory: /home/patrick/code/testedb                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  Output:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ================                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           


  Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  ================                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/patrick/code/testedb-deploy/releases/20171015162057/app/config/parameters.yml': No such file or directory
```

This is my deploy file:

```
<?php

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Deployer\DefaultDeployer;

return new class extends DefaultDeployer
{
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->getConfigBuilder()
            ->server('localhost')
            ->deployDir('/home/patrick/code/testedb-deploy')
            ->repositoryUrl('git@github.com:superpatty/symfony-demo.git')
            ->symfonyEnvironment('prod')
            ->resetOpCacheFor('https://demo.symfony.com')
        ;
    }

    public function beforeStartingDeploy()
    {
        $this->log('Checking that the repository is in a clean state.');

        $this->log('Running tests, linters and checkers.');
        $this->runLocal('./bin/console security:check --env=dev');
        $this->runLocal('./bin/console lint:twig app/Resources/ --no-debug');
        $this->runLocal('./bin/console lint:yaml app/ --no-debug');
        $this->runLocal('./bin/console lint:xliff app/Resources/ --no-debug');
        $this->runLocal('./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit');
    }

    public function beforeFinishingDeploy()
    {
    }
};
```

Has anyone else come across this issue and how to get around it?